# Facebook app is just posting content on my wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created a Facebook app which will share a link to users wall 
but the issue is the link is posted on my wall but not on any other user's wall 
i have put on live link [Link to post on wall app](https://uthpack.com/kashmir/wall.php)

the code of app that will post on users wall is given below is there anything i need to approve it from the facebook or is there any mistake in my code please i need a real help any one could do ?
waiting for your kind response i am new to the Facebook API

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
            appId: '763390233734216', // App ID from the app dashboard
            //channelUrl : '//local.facebook-test/channel.html',  // Channel file for x-domain comms
            status: true, // Check Facebook Login status
            xfbml: true, // Look for social plugins on the page
            oauth: true // Enable oauth authentication
        });

        // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here

        FB.login(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                console.log(response.authResponse.accessToken);

                var params = {};

                params['name'] = 'Seasons Canola';
                params['description'] = 'Description';
                params['link'] = 'http://vimeo.com/99708842';

                FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
                    if (!response || response.error) {
                        alert('Error occured');
                    } else {
                        alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
                    }
                });




            } else {
                alert('Not logged in');
            }
        }, {
            scope: 'public_profile,email,publish_actions'
        });

    };

    // Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Comment: Two things:
A: Do you allow the user to customize the message that will come along with the link you will publish?
B: You specify "me/feed" so you will only past on the wall of the user that logged in to your Facebook Application.

Comment: no user will not able to customize this message
what i need to change in code if user can able to change the message?

Comment: I am 99.9% sure that your app is not approved for the use of the publish_actions permission. You should submit it for review and wait for the response of Facebook. Only if they approve your use of publish_actions your users will be asked for it during login.

Comment: params['message'] = 'The user his custom input'; If you do not allow the user to customize that message parameter, you won't get any approval. That is a fact ;)